# visually indicate to the user when the textbox limit has been exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am new asp.net now I need to visually indicate to the user when the textbox limit exceeded. Please give a solution.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Txtbox" runat="server" Height="50px" TextMode="MultiLine"
        Width="150px" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the help of `JQuery` so when use type in the text, it shows how much characters are left.

[Refer this for the whole step by step implementation](http://aj-learning.com/blog/visually-indicate-user-textbox-limit-exceeded/)

Answer (score 0):

In your textbox, add this

```
onkeypress="return CheckLength(this.value,50);"
```

The javascript function `CheckLength`

```
function CheckLength(ctrl, maxlen) {
    var textbox = ctrl;
    if (textbox.length >= maxlen) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This will prevent you from entering more than 50 characters in the textbox. You can add a tooltip next to the textbox, perhaps

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMark1" runat="server" Text="You can enter 50 characters only." Font-Size="0.65em"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="Jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var limit = 50;
        var $tb = $('textarea[id$=TextBox1]');
        $tb.keyup(function () {
            var len = $(this).val().length;
            if (len > limit) {
                $(this).addClass('exceeded');
                $('#msg').text(len - limit + " characters exceeded");
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('exceeded');
                $('#msg').text(limit - len + " characters left");
            }
        });
        $('input[id$=btnSubmit]').click(function (e) {
            var len = $tb.val().length;
            if (len > limit) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

TextBox

```
 <asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" height="100px" textmode="MultiLine" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
        Width="250px" MaxLength="10"></asp:textbox>
        <span id="msg"></span>
          <br />
        <asp:button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" text="Submit" xmlns:asp="#unknown" />
```

css:

```
.exceeded
    {
    background-color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function CheckTextLength(text, long) {
    var maxlength = new Number(long); // Change number to your max length.
    if (text.value.length > maxlength) {
        text.value = text.value.substring(0, maxlength);
        $('#YourErrorDivid').empty().append(" Only " + long + " characters allowed");
    }
}

 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Txtbox" Width="450px" TextMode="MultiLine"
            onKeyPress="CheckTextLength(this,50)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#Txtbox").on('input',function () {
    if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')) {
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NuLP3/3/)

Showing an outline because, it wont take up any space. I'm also removing the outline if the user removes some characters.

```
$("#txtName").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length >= $(this).attr('maxLength'))
    {
        $(this).css('outline','2px solid red');
    }
    else 
    {
        $(this).css('outline','');
    }
});
```